# ZF2 redirect() not working while header location does

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I have a controller with an index action in which I use a redirect to route:

```php
$this->redirect()->toRoute('dummy-route')->setStatusCode('301');
```

This works on my local development machine, but as soon as I deploy it to staging the redirect is not working anymore.
I have set a header('Location: ') just to see if redirects are working and it does work as expected.

What can be making the zf2 redirect to not work on the second machine?

@noobie-php Yeah sure, here is the code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->redirect()->toRoute('base-calculator')->setStatusCode('301');
    exit;
}
```

And routes:

```
'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
                    'base-calculator' => array(
                            'type'    => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                    'route'    => '/calculate[/:criteriaFirst][/:criteriaSecond]',
                                    'constraints' => array(
                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                            'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array(
                                            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                            'action'     => 'calculator',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    )
```

Comment: would you mind posting rotues and action

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have a `return` statement in front of it?

```
return $this->redirect()->to route('foo/bar');
```

/edit: Ok, now I know you haven't, here an explanation.

The framework has a concept called short-circuiting. This means that whenever you return a response during route or dispatch, this response will be send to the client immediately. This is done without rendering view scripts, etc, to speed things up a little bit.

The Redirect plugin creates a Response object where the status code is set (to either 301 or 302) and a Location header injected. This location header includes the new url you want to redirect to.

If you do not place `return` in front of this call, a Response object is created but never given back to short circuit. It just remains somewhere hidden inside the framework. Based on your own business logic, you might sometimes get redirected, but most times not.

So, like [the manual also points out](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-redirect), you have to use `return` to make this short-circuiting possible

Comment: I have no return before the redirect. Should I? Always happy to learn something new, so a link or explanation is more than welcome.

Comment: See my edit. It was just a wild guess, now I know you didn't; here is the explanation :)